# delete/free memory allocated by malloc and reused by new

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator, free

In the following program `new` reuses a memory allocated by `malloc`. But how to free the memory then? by `free` or by `delete`? how to call the destructor?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A()  {}
    ~A() {}
};
int main()
{
    void* p = malloc(sizeof(A));
    A* pa = new (p) A();

    // codes...


    delete pa;
    // pa ->~A();
    // free(p);
}
```

Is it safe to reuse `malloc` memory by `new`? And how to free the memory?

Comment: For your case `free()` should be used.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ a class may need a call to destructor. how to call the destructor? explicitly before freeing? or after freeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new (p) A()` is [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) that doesn't allocate memory and only calls the constructor.

Calling regular `delete` on that pointer returned by placement new is undefined behaviour.

To deallocate correctly here you need to call the destructor and then `free` the memory:

```
pa->~A(); // or, in C++17 std::destroy_at(pa);
free(pa);
```

Comment: can `destroy_at` be used anywhere one needs to call the destructor explicitly?

Comment: @nano I do not see why not. Unless you want to avoid `#include <memory>`.